# Simulate sed read command with awk

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I want to stimulate use of `sed`:

```
sed  '3r awk.scr' awk.script
```

with `awk.scr`:

```
a
b
c 
d 
e 
f
```

and `awk.script` as:

```
hello there is
hello i'am there is
hello sdfdf
dfdfdf aads
23213 3 434
```

Using `awk` here:

```
awk 'BEGIN {while((getline gf < "awk.script") > 0) {print gf; if(++i > 2) break;} {while((getline bf < "awk.scr")> 0 ) { print bf}}}'
```

But its too complex is there a easy way out.

Desired output:

```
hello there is
hello i'am there is
hello sdfdf
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

Comment: Are you sure the desired output is what you got when you run `sed  '2r awk.scr' awk.script`? It should be `3r` instead of `2r`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easier way can be:

```
awk 'FNR == 3 {print;while(getline < "awk.scr") print; next};1' awk.script
```

or:

```
awk 'FNR == 4 {while(getline < "awk.scr") print};1' awk.script
```

With this approach, you only need to care about the `awk.scr`, `awk` will process `awk.script` for you.

Comment: thanks for response. Love the neat code.Can you explain are you using flag with `1` option. Why does it require next when there already is a while loop?

Comment: The `1` is a true expression, cause `awk` `print $0` by default. The `next` there to stop `awk` executing `1` expression after the while loop, otherwise, you will print the third line two times. I updated with another solution without the `next`.

Comment: thanks for explanation, i tested the original cmd without `next` and with it and it had no difference of the output. There was no printing of the third line x3 times.

Comment: Even, then It has no effect on o/p.

Comment: It's actually a blank line, `$0` set by `getline` was empty after `print`.